# after installing my app in google play store, the 'open' button disappear how to handle it?

Tags: android

i build an android app, publish my app on play store and create a dynamic link.

i click the dynamic link, link redirect me to play store.
then i install my app in play store and the installation is finished, the 'open' button is disappear

i can't understand why this is happened.

if i don't use those dynamic links, search my app and install my app in play store, the play store show me the 'open' button properly.

can someone advice me plz?

++ dynamic links work fine if my app installed, and this is my launcher activity's intent filters

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="aaa" />
    <data android:scheme="bbb" />
    <data android:scheme="ccc" />
</intent-filter>
```

i sent a mail to google developer, but their answer was so hard to understand becuase its translation is very weired

Comment: Can you please post their answer?

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line from your code

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

You shouldn't use `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.action.VIEW` in same activity